# Ubuntu Thinks I Have Two Monitors

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, display

Ubuntu thinks I have two monitors when I'm on a laptop. Here is my setup:

- Lenovo W520
- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- Nvidia Proprietary drivers (340.46)

Symptoms: Display (and nvidia-settings) shows a monitor on DFP-0 and CRT-0

I'm having trouble debugging this, my xorg.conf looks fine. Could anyone suggest some possible solutions or avenues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use the xorg-edgers ppa and downgrade the drivers to 304...

**Uninstall Manually Installed Driver**

```
sudo NVIDIA-something-something --uninstall
```

**Add Xorg Edgers**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install 304 Drivers because old drivers are better**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-304-dev
```